# PHP namespace function/variable hiding

Tags: php, namespaces, scope

Is there any way to change scope?

Lets say I have a nmespace with 10 functions but i want only 4 of them to be available to call from outside(another 6 are 'private' and only used by those 4). Or what should i do to hide those functions?

Comment: You answered your question yourself. You need to focus on classes and encapsulation, but not on namespaces. Just create a class with 6 private methods and 4 public ones.

Comment: @Axalix strange. I was trying to get rid of all my 100% static classes by using namespaces.

Comment: Namespaces are a mechanism to allow multiple classes/functions with the same name to co-exist, not as a means of eliminating static classes